# Add echo as described by difference equation to audio signal (in MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, convolution, linear-systems

A simple linear system is echo. It can be described by equation 
$$
y[n] = x[n]+ k\,x[n−d],
$$ where $n$ represents sample index, $k$ represents an attenuation coefficient, and $d$ represents time lag.

How can I add echo to an input signal in MATLAB with convolution?

I'm new at MATLAB.

Comment: Hint: what is the impulse response of a system that outputs $y[n]$ when the input is $x[n]$?

Comment: I fixed the question. Input is just an audio signal not x[n]. So the question is how can i add echo with lag and attenuation factor based on that equation to some audio signal? I would really appreciate if someone can demonstrate me this in matlab.

Comment: Other hint: Think about expressing this formula via matrix operations. What sort of matrix operation could give you $y[n]$?

Answer (score 1):

The impulse response $h[n]$ can be obtained by inspection:
$$
h[n] = \delta[n] + k \delta[n - d]
$$

In MATLAB notation this would be:

```
h = [1, zeros(1,d-1), k];
```

The output is computed by:

```
y = conv(x, h);
```

Note that the time sample indices for the vector `y` will be as follows, assuming that both `x` and `h` are indexed where the first element corresponds to time $n=0$:

```
ny = 0:(length(x) + length(h) - 2);
```